# workaround lambda 500MB ephemeral storage

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I want to write a Lambda function to retrieve an s3 object, download it to the /tmp folder of the function, then run the crypto.createHash(algorithm) on the object. But I need a solution for object size over 500MB since that's a Lambda ephemeral storage limit. Is there any workaround for this? 
Also what if the object I am retrieving is in Glacier-storage class from the bucketpolicy how do I download it using Lambda? would I need one lambda for retrieval and another for download? any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't recommend using Lambda for that. You are charged for fractions of 100ms and retrieve 500Mb will take a lot of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** You can now provision up to 10GB of ephemeral storage with your Lambda functions.

---

You should be able to stream the contents of an S3 object into your hash algorithm without ever having to store it in the `/tmp` folder. You shouldn't have to store it to the local disk at all.

Regarding files stored in Glacier, since that can take so long yes you would have to trigger the restore from one function invocation, and then trigger another invocation to compute the hash once the object has been restored.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Streaming the content to the hash algorithm works, but only for smaller size files, when I tried it with bigger size files the function times out on me, even if I increase the lambda memory size configuration to max. Any other ideas in terms of trying to use lambda to calculate hash of big size S3 object?

Comment: @Calvin Did you solve the problem? Presumably, as well as increasing the RAM size to get correspondingly more CPU, you also increased the Lambda function timeout itself.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else landing here, AWS just released a feature making ephemeral storage configurable up to 10G.

Links:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/

https://medium.com/slalom-build/unlocking-new-potentials-in-aws-lambda-with-larger-ephemeral-storage-f6fa6d49f021